# Conditional formatting of apache log file

Tags: apache, logging, formatting

Is it possible to invoke conditional formatting in the actual format of the log entry in apache?

For example, my current formatting looks like this for access logs:

```
0.0.0.0 - - %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T %V %A
```

The reason I have the "%A" there at the end is to see if they accessed the site via the ipv6 or ipv4 address (not logging the users ip). My question is, is it possible to make it so instead of writing the actual ip of the interface used, it would simply write "v4" or "v6"?

I know this can be done as a post-process but am wondering if it's possible "on-the-fly" so to speak.

Currrently using Apache/2.2.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is it possible to make it so instead of writing the actual ip of the interface used, it would simply write "v4" or "v6"?

Well, there is no sophisticated "if-else" construct available there.

But you could try to set an environment variable beforehand - and then have the content of that logged via `%{VARNAME}e`.

```
SetEnvIf Server_Addr 127\.0\.0\.1 IP_VERSION=v4
SetEnvIf Server_Addr /*whatevertheipv6addresslookslikeasregexp*/ IP_VERSION=v6
```

And in your log format specification `%{IP_VERSION}e` to have the content of that variable logged.

(Not tested, just inferred from docs. No guarantee.)